# How can an async Knex query be run at a debugger statement's execution halt?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, knex.js

If I hardcode and `await` a Knex query statement into the code and `console.log()` it prior to hitting the `debugger` statement, I get the expected output. However, after hitting a `debugger` statement, I would like to be able to execute some additional Knex queries, but I either don't receive the expected response or I receive an error. For example, here are some statements I tried in the console while halted at a debugger statement, along with the outputs:

```js
knex("users").where({username: "raj"})
```

> Builder {client: Client_PG, and: Builder, _single: Object, _statements: Array(1), _method: "select", …}

```js
console.log(knex("users").where({username: "raj"}))
```

> Builder {client: Client_PG, and: Builder, _single: Object, _statements: Array(1), _method: "select", …}

```js
await knex("users").where({username: "raj"})
```

> *SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function*

```js
await console.log(knex("users").where({username: "raj"}))
```

> *SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function*

```js
console.log(await knex("users").where({username: "raj"}))
```

> *SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list*

I'm using VSCode, so I tried pressing the **Step Over** and **Step Into** button many times (until the full stack ended) as well, but I never received the expected output in the console.

What would be the right way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The error that you see its because every `await` should be called in an `async` function.

Im not sure where are you trying to execute the query, but you can try a *top-level await* syntax:

```js
const executeQuery = async () => {
    try {
        const result= await knex("users").where({username: "raj"})
        console.log({result})
    } catch (error) {
        console.log({error})
    }
})

executeQuery()
```

Or the same, with *inmediate executed function* syntax (hard to read in my opinion):

```js
(async () => {
    try {
        const result= await knex("users").where({username: "raj"})
        console.log({result})
    } catch (error) {
        console.log({error})
    }
})()
```

Comment: I'm trying to execute queries while execution is breaked at a `debugger` statement (so I can tinker). The `debugger` statement is within an `async` function in all of my examples, yet I if I use `await` I still get the error shown in my 3rd and 4th examples.